# How do you use SSIS SQL logging and a Config Files using SQL Server Table?

Tags: sql-server, configuration, ssis

I have created a package in SSIS where I am using the logging option of "SSIS Log provider for SQL Server". I am also using the package configuration of "SQL Server" where I store all the package connection information in a table with the exception of the connections to my log provider and my configuration provider. The reason I do this is because I assume the package can't set up a connection to the configuration settings table if I store the information to access it there. Also FYI, my package properties are set to "DontSaveSensitive".

Now I know that my package cannot connect to the config files settings that are in a table and it cannot do logging unless it has the connection information that does that. I assume this has to be done in the sql server agent, how do I set that info for the one connection?

I suppose the main question is how the heck do I set up a package with SQL logging and a config file in SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create package variables for the connection information, use the variables in expressions for the connection strings in the package, and set the values of those variables when you call the package from the SQL Agent job.

At least that's one way to do it.

Another is to populate the connection string variable from a config file.

Comment: Are you saying create a package parameter of the connection string and then passing that parameter in via the SQL agent job? Testing now.

Comment: Yes, parameter or, before 2012, variable.

Comment: What fixed it was creating a variable of the connection string and saving that in my SSIS configurations. That's all that was needed, I did not need to set the values of the variable in the SQL agent job. If thats what you meant could you edit your answer. I have marked this correct.

Comment: That is another way to do it.  I didn't suggest it because from the way your question was worded, I thought you weren't able to use a config file for some reason.